# Getting Bad Magic Number while Decrypting the file

Tags: python, encryption, openssl, aes

Here i am encrypting the file using below code using python and i am getting the encrypted file as expected.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64

def pad(s):
    return s + b"\0" * (AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size)

def encrypt_file(input_path, output_path, key):
    with open(input_path, 'rb') as f:
        plaintext = f.read()
        plaintext = pad(plaintext)
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC)
        ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(plaintext)
        with open(output_path, 'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(base64.b64encode(ciphertext))

key = b'0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef'
input_path = 'path/item_properties_part2/sample.csv'
output_path = 'path/enc/sample.csv'

encrypt_file(input_path, output_path, key)
```

But when I am trying to decrypt the using OpenSSL (OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 - version) using below command I am getting `bad magic number` error.

I am using below command

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in sample_final.csv -out decsample_final.csv -k 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef
```

My requirement is encrypting the file using python and decrypting the encrypted file using openssl.

Please help to solve this error. It will be a great help.

Comment: CBC requires an IV. Since you do not specify an IV in the Python code, a random IV is generated. You can get this after encryption with `cipher.iv`. This is missing in the code. You need the IV for decryption!

Comment: Also, when decrypting with OpenSSL, key and IV must be specified hex encoded (!) with the `-K` (not `-k`) and `-iv` options. Other incompatibilities are: Zero Padding in Python code (note PyCryptodome has a padding module) and PKCS#7 in OpenSSL, Base64 encoding of the ciphertext in the Python code and no Base64 decoding in the OpenSSL statement. You should have a look at the PyCryptodome and OpenSSL docs!

Comment: You mean to say IV will be generated randomly in python code since we have not defined, but while decrypting we need to run as below command ```openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in encrypted_file -out decrypted_file -K <hex_key> -iv <hex_iv>
```

Comment: Yes, but the incompatibilities regarding padding and Base64 encoding also need to be fixed.

Comment: i have added IV in the code as follow ```cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)```I ran following command  to decrypt ```openssl enc -d -base64 -aes-256-cbc -d -in sample_final.csv -out decsample_final_3.csv -k 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef -iv 0123456789abcdef```  now i am getting ```error reading input file```

Comment: Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python code below:

- pads with PKCS#7 using the PyCryptodome padding module
- determines the IV generated during encryption
- stores the raw data instead of the Base64 encoded data
- outputs key and IV hex encoded

```py
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad

def encrypt_file(input_path, output_path, key):
    with open(input_path, 'rb') as f:
        plaintext = f.read()
    plaintext = pad(plaintext, 16)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC)
    ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(plaintext)
    with open(output_path, 'wb') as outfile:
        outfile.write(ciphertext)
    return cipher.iv

key = b"0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef"
input_path = '<input path>'
output_path = '<output_path>'
iv = encrypt_file(input_path, output_path, key)
print(key.hex()) # 3031323334353637383961626364656630313233343536373839616263646566
print(iv.hex()) # e.g. 562540db83c746da3967c93b4d545884
```

The following OpenSSL statement:

- specifies the hex encoded key using the `-K` option
- specifies the hex encoded IV using the `-iv` option
- uses PKCS#7 by default and does not perform Base64 decoding (matching the encryption settings)

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in <path to input enc file> -out <path to dec file> -K 3031323334353637383961626364656630313233343536373839616263646566 -iv 562540db83c746da3967c93b4d545884
```

With this OpenSSL statement, the file with the encrypted data generated with the Python code can be successfully decrypted.

---

If the ciphertext in the file is to be Base64 encoded after encryption, the OpenSSL statement must contain the option `-base64 -A` so that the data is Base64 decoded before decryption.

If the user defined padding (zero padding) is to be used for encryption, disable padding with the option `-nopad` in the OpenSSL statement. Note that the 0x00 padding bytes are not removed.

Consider that storing the raw data is more efficient than storing the Base64 encoded data and that PKCS#7 padding is reliable as opposed to zero padding.

Comment: @Sharma
 - Please post a new question, if necessary you can refer to this post (also, code should generally not be posted in comments as this is unreadable). Thx.