# Getting Data must be padded to 16 byte boundary in CBC mode when decrypting the file

Tags: python, encryption, openssl, aes

I am trying to decrypt the file which I have encrypted using following link(python encryption code)
[Getting Bad Magic Number while Decrypting the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75665392/getting-bad-magic-number-while-decrypting-the-file/)

But when i am trying to decrypt the code getting following error:
`ValueError: Data must be padded to 16 byte boundary in CBC mode`
Decryption Code:

```
def decrypt_file(input_file_path, output_file_path, key):
    """
    Decrypt the given input file with the given key using AES and save the result to the given output file.
    """
    with open(input_file_path, "rb") as input_file:
        with open(output_file_path, "wb") as output_file:
            iv = input_file.read(AES.block_size)
            cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
            while True:
                chunk = input_file.read(1024 * AES.block_size)
                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break
                output_file.write(cipher.decrypt(chunk))
```

Note: Decryption using open ssl is working fine using following command `openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in sample.csv -out output_test.csv -K 30313233343536373839616263646566303132333435363453839616263646566 -iv 310401d79e639349639088859d7f433`

Now i want to decrypt using python before decryption we are splitting the encrypted file into 4 chunk and trying to decrypt the each chunk separately using above code, but i am getting above error, please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You need to use the same steps for decrypting as you did for encryption ! Your decryption code assumes that the iv is prepended in the file, but your encryption code did not prepend the iv. Also, your encryption code base64 encode the data, but your decryption code do not do base64 decoding ..

Comment: In the encryption code posted in your linked question, the *implicitly* generated IV is used for encryption, but it is not determined with `cipher.iv` and is therefore lost. Thus decryption is not possible at all (at least for CBC the first block cannot be decrypted anymore).

Comment: Therefore, you have to fix the *encryption* code so that the IV is available during decryption: output the IV, concatenate IV and ciphertext, etc. Ultimately, the decryption code depends on this fix. See also the answer to the linked question regarding Base64 encoding and padding.

Answer (score 3):

As seen by the error message, AES operating in CBC mode - encrypted bytes must be in multiple of 16-byte blocks.

To achieve this, there are inbuilt methods called `pad` and `unpad`, from the `Crypto.Util.Padding` package, that can be `import`'ed and invoked from there.

Your final code will resemble the following:

Encryption

```
plaintext_padded = pad(plaintext, AES.block_size)
ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(plaintext_padded)
```

Decryption

```
ciphertext_padded = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
plaintext = unpad(ciphertext_padded, AES.block_size)
```

HTH